# Web browser control does not load properly C#

Tags: c#

i load a web page in my web browser control in C#.

my code :

[image]

but one part of the webpage doesn't appear properly in web browser.please look :
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using modern HTML/CSS/JavaScript in that page - which the `WebBrowser` control doesn't support.

The `WebBrowser` control in WinForms wraps `MSHTML.dll`, which is the same engine as Internet Explorer 11 (last updated in 2013). Modern HTML and JavaScript simply is not supported.

Your options are either:

- Don't use HTML, CSS and JavaScript features not supported by Internet Explorer 11.
- Use the `EdgeHtml.dll`-based `WebView` control - but this is only supported on Windows 10.
- Use an embedded Chromium control. There are a variety of vendors, though `CefSharp` is a popular one.
- Don't display content inside your application window and let the user browse the content in their own browser of choice.

  - If you're displaying HTML generated by your application, then run a local web-server.

Comment: i set values from my win app by get element.what should i do ? no other way ?

Comment: disabling java script can solve ? is it possible in web browser ?

Comment: It does support modern HTML/Scripting.  Google "webbrowser control compatibility", first hit is good.

Comment: @HansPassant It depends on your definition of “modern”. I’d love to be able to use ES6 native modules in all my web-projects, but the 10-20% of our user base still using IE11 is the blocking factor.